# Why this RE(SIGSEGV) Error comes in C++ while submitting?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

In the time of code submission I got RE(SIGSEGV) error. 
My code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T,val,v;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int N,M;
    cin >> T;
    while(T--){
        cin >> N >> M;
        vector<int> vec(M+1,0);
        vector<int> arr1;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin >> v;
            arr1.push_back(v);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            cin >> val;
            vec[arr1[j]]+=val;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<=M;i++){
            if((vec[arr1[i]])<min && (vec[arr1[i]])!=0){
                min = vec[arr1[i]];
            }
        }
        cout << " box: "<<endl;
        for(int a=0;a<vec.size();a++){
            cout << vec[a] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << min << endl;
        vec.clear();
        arr1.clear();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Problem link: https://www.codechef.com/MARCH20B/problems/CHPINTU .
Can anyone tell me why is this happening? How can I overcome this problem?
**Thank you.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: You're reading in values from the user, and then using those values as indices into another vector without any checks.   A recipe that virtually guarantees running out of bounds in accessing elements of a vector/array.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Might be useful to also mention the problem that you're trying to solve with this code.

Comment: All user inputs are in INTEGER. It only shows error me for large inputted value. @Peter

Comment: I've just mentioned the problem. Check it out- https://www.codechef.com/MARCH20B/problems/CHPINTU @dragosht

Comment: Please provide a [mre], what is the failing input and what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: @RidaFarhan  - That's my point.  If you use an integer as an index to access elements of a vector or array, that integer needs to be non-negative and less than the number of elements in that vector/array. Your code uses input integers as indices to elements of an array, with no check they are in range. Arrays and vectors don't magically grow if you use an invalid index.For example, one loop reads elements into array `arr1` and the next loop uses elements of `arr1` as indices into `vec` - as in `vec[arr1[j]]+=val;`.   If any of the `arr1[j]` are `vec.size()` or more, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I understood. But In question they also clearly mentioned that the inputted value will be in range for sure. If it is possible you should check the problem -  https://www.codechef.com/MARCH20B/problems/CHPINTU. @Peter

Comment: If `arr1[i]` is the type of fruit in basket `i`, and `vec[i]` is the price of basket `i`, what is `vec[arr1[i]]`? (You need to practice variable naming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N could be smaller than M, in that case this could lead to segmentation errors:

```
for(int i=1;i<=M;i++){
    if((vec[arr1[i]])<min && (vec[arr1[i]])!=0){
        min = vec[arr1[i]];
    }
}
```

You should be instead looking over *vec[i]* instead of *vec[arr1[i]]*

Nit: this would still give you WA(Wrong Answer) but will not result in SIGSEGV, one of the errors I can find is only initializing *min* at start, instead of initializing it with INT_MAX in the loop over *T*